# geom_text labels don't align with geom_bar / position_dodge2 if width is changed

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I am creating a barplot in `ggplot2` 3 which includes `facet_grid` and `position_dodge2(preserve="single")` (= same bar width in all facets) as well as `geom_text` for labeling. It works all fine except when I change the width of the bars with `width`, e.g to 1.2 (otherwise the bars are rather slim).

Two problems occur:

- the labels of geom_text don't align any longer with the bars;
- the bars aren't centered on the x axis as they should.

Any solution to this? A workaround with `hjust` doesn't seem to work since labels are not evenly misaligned when changing `width`. Or am I getting something wrong regarding the purpose of `width` ?

[This](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1254) seems related to my question.

Data:

```
x <- structure(list(SessionLastStage = structure(1:20, .Label = c("1998-1999", 
                                                                  "1999-2000", "2000-2001", "2001-2002", "2002-2003", "2003-2004", 
                                                                  "2004-2005", "2005-2006", "2006-2007", "2007-2008", "2008-2009", 
                                                                  "2009-2010", "2010-2011", "2011-2012", "2012-2013", "2013-2014", 
                                                                  "2014-2015", "2015-2016", "2016-2017", "2017-2018"), class = "factor"), 
                    freq = c(0, 2, 18, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 14, 8, 16, 30, 4, 12, 
                             10, 11, 30, 1, 0), Phase = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L
                             ), .Label = c("Introduction", "Maintenance", "Deconsolidation"
                             ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                        -20L), .Names = c("SessionLastStage", "freq", "Phase"))
```

plot command:

```
x %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(x=SessionLastStage, y=freq), 
           stat="identity", 
           width=1.2, 
           position = position_dodge2(preserve="single"))+ 
  geom_text(data=x %>% filter(freq>0),
            aes(x=SessionLastStage, y=freq+1, label=freq))+
  facet_grid(.~Phase, 
             scales="free_x", 
             space = "free_x")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(angle=90))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `position_dodge`? You don't actually have multiple bars per x value (within facets), so I don't think you really need it. If you're using `position_dodge` to change the look of the plot, there's probably another way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Why don't you simply use  `geom_bar(aes(x=SessionLastStage, y=freq), stat="identity")` and control the bar width by adjusting the plot size?